# How to list several specific files from amazon S3 quickly

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to check if some files are really in my s3 bucket. Using aws cli I can do it for one files with ls like

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/file/path/file001.jpg
```

but I need to be able to do it for several files

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/file/path/file001.jpg ls s3://mybucket/file/path/file002.jpg
```

Won't work

nor

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/file/path/file001.jpg s3://mybucket/file/path/file005.jpg
```

Of course

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/file/path/file001.jpg;
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/file/path/file005.jpg
```

Works perfectly, but slowly. It takes about 1 sec to get one file, because it connects an close the connection each time.

I've hundreds of files to check on a regular basis, so I need a fast way to do it. Thanks

I'm not insisting on using ls, or passing a path, a "find" of the filenames would also do (but aws cli seems to lack find). Another tool (as long as it can be invoked with the command line), will be ok

I don’t want to get a list of all files or have a script looking at all files and then post process. I need a way to ask s3 give me fila a,r,z in one go.

I think s3api listobjects call should be the one but I fail at its syntax to ask several file names at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that using python boto3 sdk for AWS

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket=s3.Bucket('mausamrest');

for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    print(obj.key)
```

where **mausamrest** is the bucket

Comment: you can use any other popular programming languages too , AWS provide sdk's for all popular languages such as java, python, c++, go, javascript

Comment: I don’t want all files, but a list of arbitrary file names. Also it needs to be fast so no re-connection

Comment: @glitchtracker Just use the above code, then add logic to check for the specific files of interest. No reconnections required, very fast.

Comment: hi Mausam, something very strange hapened, I ran your code, forgeting to change the bucket name, and I was able to list YOUR files, is that normal ?

Comment: So I tried your code, adding if obj.key=='myfile' just before print(obj.key), it worked, but it's slow as hell, as, as I've feared it executes the if for all my 100000 files. Sure I could exit the code when the last file is found, but it won't help if one of my file is the last one of the bucket

Comment: hi @glitchtracker you are able to see my objects as my bucket and objects have public read access, don't worry about that, i know about it.